# Really minimum lisp

Tags: lisp, turing-complete

What is the minimum set of primitives required such that a language is Turing complete and a lisp variant?

Seems like car, cdr and some flow control and something for REPL is enough. It be nice if there is such list.

Assume there are only 3 types of data, integers, symbols and lists.(like in picolisp)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unlambda

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that Unlambda is a LISP-variant.

Comment: i mentioned it just for fun, and it is functional

Comment: Note that integers are unnecessary, you can implement them from pure functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a good discussion of this in the [Lisp FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/lisp-faq/part1/section-6.html). It depends on your choice of primitives. McCarthy's original "LISP 1.5 Programmer's Manual" did it with five functions: CAR, CDR, CONS, EQ, and ATOM.

Comment: Reading said FAQ, it appears he used those five functions along with the special forms CONS, LAMBDA and QUOTE.

Answer (score 13):

The [lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) is turing complete.   It has one primitive - the lambda.  Translating that to a lisp syntax is pretty trivial.

Comment: Actually it has *three* primitives: lambda expressions, function calls, and variable references.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the minimum set is what John McCarthy published in the original paper.

[The Roots of Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/rootsoflisp.html).

[The code](http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/paulgraham/jmc.lisp).

Answer (score 3):

The best way to actually know this for sure is if you implement it. I used 3 summers to create [Zozotez](http://sylwester.no/zozotez/) which is a McCarty-ish LISP running on [Brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck).

I tried to find out what I needed and on a forum you'll find a thread that says [You only need lambda.](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3847#comment-57441) Thus, you can make a whole LISP in lambda calculus if you'd like. I found it interesting, but it's hardly the way to go if you want something that eventually has side effects and works in the real world.

For a Turing complete LISP I used [Paul Grahams explanation of McCarthy's paper](http://www.paulgraham.com/rootsoflisp.html) and all you really need is:

- symbol-evaluation
- special form quote
- special form if (or cond)
- special form lambda (similar to quote)
- function eq
- function atom
- function cons
- function car
- function cdr
- function-dispatch (basically apply but not actually exposed to the system so it handles a list where first element is a function)

Thats 10. In addition to this, to have a implementation that you can test and not just on a drawing board:

- function read
- function write

Thats 12. In my [Zozotez](http://sylwester.no/zozotez/) I implemeted `set` and `flambda` (anonymous macroes, like lambda) as well. I could feed it a library implementing any dynamic bound lisp (Elisp, picoLisp) with the exception of file I/O (because the underlying BF does not support it other than stdin/stdout).

I recommend anyone to implement a LISP1-interpreter, in both `LISP` and `(not LISP)`, to fully understand how a language is implemented. LISP has a very simple syntax so it's a good starting point. For all other programming languages how you implement  an interpreter is very similar. Eg. in the [SICP videos](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/) the wizards make an interpreter for a logical language, but the structure and how to implement it is very similar to a lisp interpreter even though this language is completely different than Lisp.